# Select Sum as var : php

Tags: php, mysql

T want to select the total sum of a numeric column from two table, when I add my two var i get always 0 
what is my wrong.

my code :

```
$ecoles_classes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT (SUM(classes)) as total FROM wp_ecoles_details ");
$mairie_classes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT (SUM(classes)) as total FROM wp_mairie_details ");
$ecoles_classes_var = $ecoles_classes->total ;
$mairie_classes_var = $mairie_classes->total ;
$ecole_maire_classes = $ecoles_classes_var + $mairie_classes_var
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($ecole_maire_classes) ?>" id="result_1" >
```

Comment: Can u show exactly what the result of the queries is?

Comment: print out `$ecoles_classes_var` and `$mairie_classes_var` and check what are you getting there ? or, do **var_dump** `$ecoles_classes` and `$mairie_classes`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26754 (1) { ["total"]=> string(3) "462" } }
i add var_dump that what i get when i print my result

Comment: check scaisEdge's answer. He has updated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52385795/2469308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$ecoles_classes_var = $ecoles_classes{0}->total;
 $mairie_classes_var = $mairie_classes{0}->total;
```

Answer (score 3):

You obtain  a set of rows so you should access the proper row uisng index eg:

```
    $ecoles_classes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT (SUM(classes)) as total FROM wp_ecoles_details ");
    $mairie_classes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT (SUM(classes)) as total FROM wp_mairie_details ");
    $ecoles_classes_var = $ecoles_classes{0}->total;
    $mairie_classes_var = $mairie_classes{0}->total;
    $ecole_maire_classes = $ecoles_classes_var + $mairie_classes_var
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($ecole_maire_classes) ?>" id="result_1" >
```

fro wp doc

> $output
>
> (string) (Optional) Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants. With one of the first three, return an array of rows
>   indexed from 0 by SQL result row number. Each row is an associative
>   array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value,
>   ...), or an object. ( ->column = value ), respectively. With OBJECT_K,
>   return an associative array of row objects keyed by the value of each
>   row's first column's value. Duplicate keys are discarded.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: i get this error :"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: How do we even know what data format does `$wpdb->get_results` returns!

Comment: they return object not array